# Python: remove unwanted data to a standard json

Tags: python, json

A url has this `JSON` which is not in standard format:

```
{}&& {identifier:'ID', label:'As at 08-03-2018 5:06 PM',items:[{ID:0,N:'2ndChance W200123',SIP:'',NC:'CDWW',R:'',I:'',M:'',LT:0.009,C:0.000,VL:108.200,BV:2149.900,B:'0.008',S:'0.009',SV:7218.300,O:0.009,H:0.009,L:0.008,V:873.700,SC:'5',PV:0.009,P:0.000,BL:'100',P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:1,N:'3Cnergy',SIP:'',NC:'502',R:'',I:'',M:'t',LT:0,C:0,VL:0.000,BV:50.000,B:'0.022',S:'0.025',SV:36.000,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:0.000,SC:'2',PV:0.021,P:0,BL:'100',P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:2,N:'3Cnergy W200528',SIP:'',NC:'1E0W',R:'',I:'',M:'t',LT:0,C:0,VL:0.000,BV:0,B:'',S:'0.004',SV:50.000,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:0.000,SC:'5',PV:0.002,P:0,BL:'100',P_:'X',V_:''}`
```

I want to make all the data into list or in pandas started from ID.

`{}&& {identifier:'ID', label:'As at 08-03-2018 5:06 PM',items:` is not wanted when I requested the url

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
url ='AttributeError: 'http://www.sgx.com/JsonRead/JsonstData?qryId=RAll'
page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
alldata = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

However, I am unable to continue as the JSON format is not standard. How to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

```python
import requests
import execjs

url = 'http://www.sgx.com/JsonRead/JsonstData?qryId=RAll'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

content = page.content[len('{}&& '):] if page.content.startswith('{}&& ') else page.content
data = execjs.get().eval(content)
print(data)
```

The data is [JavaScript Object, in literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Object_literal_notation_vs_JSON).
We can use [PyExecJs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyExecJS) to eval it and get corresponding python dict.

Comment: can you elaborate more? what module you are using?

Comment: @bkcollection re and json

Comment: How to continue from `page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)`? the url is `http://www.sgx.com/JsonRead/JsonstData?qryId=RAll`. I try replace data with page but return `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'split'`. Thanks

Comment: @bkcollection Your data is not json, and has unclosed braces/brackets

Comment: yes. it is how to make it to standard json. The problem is I have to request the url first. After that, how to proceed?

Comment: @bkcollection see my updated answer